# Changing the color of Certification Logos to match the theme colors of my website

Tags: logo, copyright, legal

I have a graphic designer building me a website and I want 3 certification logos included in my credentials.

She wants to change the color of logos to a light green (to match color scheme of my logo), but I'm not sure this is allowed.

Isn't the color of a business logo trademarked or copyrighted as well?

Answer (score 1):

Copyrighted or not, certification logos/seals are *often* recognized by their visual impact.

In my opinion, even if it is permitted by the terms of the certification, I would not alter their colors. Any variation of the default color setting could possibly imply it's not a legitimate seal.

For specifics on what may or may not be permitted, you would need to check the terms of each certification seal. Some may have explicit clauses stating you are not to alter the visual appearance of the seal.

In very broad, sweeping terms, not *everything* on a web site should match the overall color theme. Too much of the same thing could actually *detract* from the overall visual impact.

Comment: Disagree, you see monochrome logo grids everywhere and no one complains or mistakes the logomark. If the brand guidelines of the company allow you to alter color then make it the color that works best on your page.

Comment: Logos and certification seals are different, at least to me. Yes greyscale logos.. don't greyscale certification identifiers. By greyscaling certification identifiers you do nothing other than devalue the importance of the certification itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you are permitted to use neutral colors, specifically black over white and white over a color, si probably you could use that.